# Set button below each one into a panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a form very similar to WhatsApp Web but in windows forms. So I want to achieve this:
[image]

I create a panel and inside that panel there is a buttons as follows:

```
    var button = new Button();
        button.Text = "test customer";
        button.Font = new Font("Arial",12, FontStyle.Bold) ;
        button.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
        button.Image = imageList1.Images[0];
        button.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        button.Width = 293;
        button.Height = 50;


    var button2 = new Button();
    button2.Text = "test customer 2";
    button2.Font = new Font("Arial",12, FontStyle.Bold) ;
    button2.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
    button2.Image = imageList1.Images[0];
    button2.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
    button2.Width = 293;
    button2.Height = 50;



    pnlCustomers.Controls.Add(button);
    pnlCustomers.Controls.Add(button2);
```

This is just for test purposes. I will create multiple buttons in a `foreach` statement, maybe 100 or more. My question is, how can I align each button one below another

**UPDATE**

I try to use `TableLayotPanel` as comments below, but something weird happen, one button goes to the top and other at the bottom of `TableLayoutPanel`, how can I fix that?

[image]

Code:

```
 var button = new Button();
            button.Text = "test customer";
            button.Font = new Font("Arial",12, FontStyle.Bold) ;
            button.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            button.Image = imageList1.Images[0];
            button.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            button.Width = 293;
            button.Height = 50;

            var button2 = new Button();
            button2.Text = "test customer 2";
            button2.Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
            button2.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            button2.Image = imageList1.Images[0];
            button2.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            button2.Width = 293;
            button2.Height = 50;

            tlpCustomers.RowCount = 2;
            tlpCustomers.AutoSize = true;
            tlpCustomers.Controls.Add(button,0,0);
            tlpCustomers.Controls.Add(button2,0,1);
```

Comment: `button.Location = new Point(requiredX, requiredY);`

Comment: Take a look at the [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel).

Comment: I try to use it but something weird happen @Dmitry

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I use TableLayoutPanel as @Dmitry suggests.

Once I do that I found an issue, one button goes to the top of panel and other at the bottom, that happen because each row have a predefined `Height` value so it is the `total of the panel height / bottom count`, to solve that I just change height value of panel as:

```
 TableLayoutRowStyleCollection styles =
     tlpCustomers.RowStyles;
            foreach (RowStyle style in styles)
            {

                style.SizeType = SizeType.Absolute;
                style.Height = 50;
            }
```

and It works:

[image]

All code:

```
  var button = new Button();
            button.Text = "test customer";
            button.Font = new Font("Arial",12, FontStyle.Bold) ;
            button.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            button.Image = imageList1.Images[0];
            button.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            button.Width = 293;
            button.Height = 50;

            var button2 = new Button();
            button2.Text = "test customer 2";
            button2.Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
            button2.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
            button2.Image = imageList1.Images[0];
            button2.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            button2.Width = 293;
            button2.Height = 50;

            tlpCustomers.RowCount = 2;

                TableLayoutRowStyleCollection styles =
         tlpCustomers.RowStyles;
                foreach (RowStyle style in styles)
                {

                    style.SizeType = SizeType.Absolute;
                    style.Height = 50;
                }
            tlpCustomers.AutoSize = true;
            tlpCustomers.Controls.Add(button,0,0);
            tlpCustomers.Controls.Add(button2,0,1);
```

if is there a more accurate solution, I really appreciate you can share that with community.